# Undefined order of side effects

Tags: c

I'm reading a C bug material and it said that:

> In a single expression itself, we may not surely guess the order of
>   the side effects. As in the following part of code, depending on
>   the compiler used, i/++ might be either 0 or 1

```
...
int i = 1;
int ii = i /++ i ;
...
```

Could you tell me the reason ?

This post has **close** problem
[Why does the expression a = a + b - ( b = a ) give a sequence point warning in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317684/why-does-the-expression-a-a-b-b-a-give-a-sequence-point-warning-in-c)

Comment: It has nothing to do with operator precedence. In your example, you only have one operator on the right hand side of the assignment, so operator precedence is clearly irrelevant.

Comment: no, there are 3 operator totally, `=` and `/` and `++`

Comment: Is space between ++ and i a typo? or that was intentionally added?

Comment: I said "on the right hand side of the assignment", but fair point, `++` is an operator too. It still has nothing to do with operator precedence, since the `++` operator is not competing with any other (it can't bind to the `/` operator, naturally), so there are no precedence questions to resolve.

Comment: I said 3 for totally, if on the right hand side  there are 2 not 1

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate with the marked question, they are different in tag and the problem is quite far different.

Comment: The dup in the colse-reason is wrong. Because that is a C++ question. But there is another dup in the info page for C whihc should have been used as close-reason..

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence is about making tree, and it won't affect the order of evaluation.

The tree should look like `((ii) = ((i) / (++(i))))` in every compiler.

On the other hand, the evaluation order is unspedified, so we cannot tell which of left hand `i` and right hand `++i` is evaluated earlier.
If former is evaluated first, the expression will be `1 / 2`, but if the latter is evaluated first, the expression will be `2 / 2`.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5 Expressions

> 2 Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. 72) Furthermore, the prior v alue
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored. 73)
>   3 The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax. 74) Except as specified
>   later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), the order of evaluation
>   of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.

Comment: This is *undefined behaviour* - the possible results are not limited to the two cases you listed